# Email verification through silverlight

Tags: sql-server, silverlight, wcf

I've built a Silverlight website where users can create an account and login. Right now, users just create an account through a form and can directly login. I want to incorporate a email verification feature, where the user will receive an email with a verification URL and only then can he login. I also wish to incorporate a forgot password feature that sends an email to the users registered email address to recover password. 
How can I do this in silverlight. I'm using Windows SQL Azure as the back-end database. Will I have to create a separate Application for creating user accounts and recovering passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope [this](http://michaelsync.net/2008/05/25/tiptrick-sending-email-in-silverlight-2-beta1) helps you out on part A of your problem.

I noticed the post might throw you off a bit, so I decided to write a method that will do this for you in the quickest amount of time.

```
public bool Send(string fromEmail, string toEmail, string subject, string body)

     {

        try

         {

             MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

             message.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);

             message.To.Add(new MailAddress(toEmail));

            message.Subject = subject;

            message.Body = body;

            message.IsBodyHtml = false;



            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

            smtp.EnableSsl = true;

            smtp.Send(message);

            return true;

        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {

            return false;

        }        

    }
```

Essentially, once they create their account you would want to call this filling out all variables.  Make sure in your body of text you have a link that sends them to a page where they can submit "activate" their account.

This will essentially be a bit value in the database that is set to false by default and won't be set to true until they click on the "submit" or "activate" button from the link that would be in the body of text.

For password recovery you would do the same.  Except instead of sending them to a page to activate their account you'd send them to a page where they could just re-create their password.  Since the database doesn't care if the password is old or new you could just send them to a page where they create a new password.  You wouldn't even need to create a temp password for them (Unless you wanted to for experience and for a extra caution).

Happy Coding! ;)

Comment: Yes, it's simply using the System.Net.Mail namespace, which you'll have to add to your Silverlight project, but will work just fine.  Read Gu's blog as it will explain things much more clear than I could ever in the minute I have to write a response.  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx